# Issue saving custom DateEdit and TimeEdit fields using a custom AppointmentEdit form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, devexpress

I have a custom `EditAppointment` form that contains 3 sets of Start and End fields. [image: See image here.]

The Start and End fields in the Planning section are the default appointment fields that are bound to Start and End in the `Scheduler` mappings.

The Start and End fields under Published and Actual are read only and are the same type of fields as under Planning (`DevExpress.XtraEditors.DateEdit` and `DevExpress.XtraEditors.TimeEdit`), but get and save their values to `CustomFields` mapped in the `Scheduler` mappings.

The custom fields are defined as Properties:

```
Public Class MyAppointmentFormController
    Inherits AppointmentFormController
    ...
    Public Property CustomPublishedStartDateTime() As DateTime
        Get
            Return CDate(EditedAppointmentCopy.CustomFields("PublishedStartDateTime"))
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As DateTime)
            EditedAppointmentCopy.CustomFields("PublishedStartDateTime") = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property CustomPublishedCompletedDateTime() As DateTime
        Get
            Return CDate(EditedAppointmentCopy.CustomFields("PublishedCompletedDateTime"))
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As DateTime)
            EditedAppointmentCopy.CustomFields("PublishedCompletedDateTime") = value
        End Set
    End Property
    ...
End Class
```

I change the Start and End dates under Planning until things line up on the timeline and then I click the <kbd>Publish</kbd> which copies data from planning to publish:

```
' Copies Planned data to Published
Private Sub btnPublishJob_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPublishJob.Click

    txtCustomPublishedPackagingLine.Text = AppointmentResourceEdit1.Text
    txtCustomPublishedRunRatePerShift.Text = txtCustomPlanningRunRatePerShift.Text
    dtPublishedStart.EditValue = dtPlanningStart.EditValue
    timePublishedStart.EditValue = New DateTime(timePlanningStart.Time.TimeOfDay.Ticks)
    dtPublishedEnd.EditValue = dtPlanningEnd.EditValue
    timePublishedEnd.EditValue = New DateTime(timePlanningEnd.Time.TimeOfDay.Ticks)
    txtCustomPublishedTotalUnits.Text = txtCustomPlannedTotalUnits.Text

End Sub
```

Then I click the <kbd>OK</kbd>:

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
   ' Required to check the appointment for conflicts.
    If (Not controller.IsConflictResolved()) Then
        Return
    End If

    ' Save Planning
    controller.DisplayStart = Me.dtPlanningStart.DateTime.Date + Me.timePlanningStart.Time.TimeOfDay
    controller.DisplayEnd = Me.dtPlanningEnd.DateTime.Date + Me.timePlanningEnd.Time.TimeOfDay

    controller.CustomPlannedRunRatePerShift = txtCustomPlanningRunRatePerShift.Text

    ' Save Published
    controller.CustomPublishedStartDateTime = Me.dtPublishedStart.DateTime.Date + Me.timePublishedStart.Time.TimeOfDay
    controller.CustomPublishedCompletedDateTime = Me.dtPublishedEnd.DateTime.Date + Me.timePublishedEnd.Time.TimeOfDay
    controller.CustomPublishedPackagingLine = txtCustomPublishedPackagingLine.Text
    controller.CustomPublishedRunRatePerShift = txtCustomPublishedRunRatePerShift.Text

    controller.Description = rtbCustomJobNotes.Text

    Try
        ' Save all changes of the editing appointment.
        controller.ApplyChanges()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

When the code reaches `controller.ApplyChanges()` I get the following error:

> FormatException occurred
>
> Input sting was not in a correct format.
>
> Troubleshooting tips:
>
> When converting a string to a DateTime, parse the string to take the
>   date before putting each variable into the DateTime object.
>
> ...

I've tried `DateTime.Parse`, `DateTime.ParseExact`, `Date.Parse`, `Date.ParseExact`, assigning the date first then adding the time, and plenty of other things, but I just can't get past this.

How should I save the dates from the custom `AppointmentEdit` form back to the sql database. I was really hoping to use the custom appointment properties to make it simple.

I'm only worried about the Published Start and End date and times.